# Shorten WSDL syntax by using defaults

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am a newbie in WSDL syntax so I am just using it in a very basic way, e.g.

```
<message name="ping_Request">
</message>
<message name="ping_Response">
  <part name="response" type="xsd:string" />
</message>

<message name="auth_Request">
  <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<message name="auth_Response">
  <part name="response" type="xsd:string" />
</message>

<portType name="ping_PortType">
  <operation name="ping">
    <input message="tns:ping_Request" />
    <output message="tns:ping_Response" />
  </operation>
</portType>

<portType name="auth_PortType">
  <operation name="auth">
    <input message="tns:auth_Request" />
    <output message="tns:auth_Response" />
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="auth_Binding" type="tns:auth_PortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="auth">
    <soap:operation soapAction="auth"/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:auth_NameSpace"/>
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:auth_NameSpace"/>
    </output>
  </operation>
</binding>

<service name="info_Service">
  <port binding="tns:ping_Binding" name="ping_Port">
    <soap:address location="https://service.example.com/info/info.php"/>
  </port> 
  <port binding="tns:auth_Binding" name="auth_Port">
    <soap:address location="https://service.example.com/info/info.php"/>
  </port> 
</service>
```

I found my self copying and pasting these blocks for any new function, modifying only the relevant keywords, so I end up with quite a long WSDL even for a relatively small number of functions.

By using WSDL defaults, is it possible to shorten this syntax to a minimum, by removing unnecessary or repeated parameters?

NOTE: this WSDL has to be read by a VB6 soap client library, which has very limited features.

Comment: I hope you're aware how obsolete the SOAP Toolkit is. Like, more obsolete than VB6. You can write your client in a .NET language, using "Add Service Reference", then expose your client as a COM object that can be consumed by VB6 or anything else like it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not the VB developer so I don't know much about it. I will pass this info to the VB6 developer which takes care of the client.